# Better way to use 'take' and 'took'

Tags: past-tense

When before sleeping if one ask me how much you drink water today. How can I respond him in better way or which one is right one?

> I **took** 5 glass of water.

or

> I **take** 5 glass of water today.

Because somehow I am using past sentence because I am going to sleep and right now am not drinking water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARG, good question. We actually don't *use* take at all for liquids. We would only use the verb *drink*.

> I drank five glasses of water today.

Similarly, we use only use the verb *eat* for food.

> I ate five cupcakes.

But we can use the verb *take* for medicine.

> I took five aspirin today.

Comment: +1 I took five aspirin (or aspirins). Thanks for the example. You **made me** check the dictionary or you **had me** check the dictionary? Or you got me check the dictionary? I doubt the last one.

Comment: @learner *Make*-, *have*-, and *let*-causatives use the bare infinitive, while *get*-causatives use the *to*-infinitive.  In other words: "I *made* you **do** it; I *had* you **do** it; I *let* you **do** it" BUT "I *got* you **to do** it".

Comment: Thank you @snailboat I got the rule right now, but which one is semantically right in the context above, made-had-let-got? If I were to use (**your example**) + "made me check the dictionary" I think it would be natural, but I am not sure about using the pronoun (**You**); it might sound rude. I mean "*You made me check the dictionary etc*". What would you say?

Comment: @learner Do you mean that reading jonlink's answer caused you to check a dictionary?  Then "You **made** me check a dictionary" would be most appropriate, but if you want to avoid saying *you*, you can avoid using a causative entirely and say "I **had to** check a dictionary" instead.

Comment: thanks for answer and comments , but then when we can use `I drunk five glasses of water today.` ? Is drank and drunk make any difference ?

Comment: @ARG We're asking and answering too many questions in the comments here.  It would be better if you asked about *drunk* and *drank* as a new question.

Comment: If I may..
Also, it would be nice to have a link to that question
because you made me wonder what the answer is.
And even more curious about how many mistakes I have just made while writing this message :))) @learner, thank you!