# You MADE/HAD/GOT me check the dictionary

Tags: causative-have, causative-make, causative-get

Earlier today, I read [an answer by jonlink](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37092/230) which used the zero plural ***aspirin***.  I wasn't sure whether that was correct, so I had to check a dictionary.  I found that both ***aspirin*** and ***aspirins*** are okay as plural forms.

If I wanted to express this in a comment, which sentence would I use?

> 1. You **made me** check the dictionary.
>   　2. You **had me** check the dictionary.

I think these first two sentences sound natural.  I'm not sure about using the pronoun ***you***, though; it might sound rude.

> 3. You **got me** check the dictionary.

This last one doesn't sound right.  Is there a problem with using ***got*** this way?

Comment: *(Note: I'm writing this question from [learner](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3156/learner)'s point of view, because I want to turn [our comment discussion](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37088/better-way-to-use-take-and-took/37092#comment68725_37092) into a question and answer.)*

Comment: The last sentence would be more idiomatic if it used the infinitive: "You got me *to check* the dictionary".

Comment: You _inspired_ me to check a dictionary :^) The verb _prompted_ might work, too.

Comment: Thank you very much snailboat. This is even much better. Thanks J.R., and actually prompt is way better than inspired. Inspired seems too big for the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, I would say all three sound unnatural - the answer didn't *make* you check the dictionary, it *prompted* you to.

Made would only be used if you're either joking (where the person clearly didn't force you to do anything) or where you've actually been forced to do something. Your example could fall into the former, but the setting isn't quite casual enough to and could potentially be seen as a criticism.

(Note that the above isn't a reflection on the StackExchange user mentioned in the initial post, or StackExchange in general, just that suggesting someone forced you to undertake an act should be done with care)

Comment: Thank you Jon. I believe "prompt" is the perfect fit. As for "made me" seeing other native speaker's answers I would not mind using it with a proper context. I have just confirmed my suspicion that it could be taken as a criticism which was my concern.

Answer (score 10):

***Make-***, ***have-***, and ***let***-causatives use bare infinitives:

> You *made* me **check** a dictionary.
>   You *had* me **check** a dictionary.
>   You *let* me **check** a dictionary.

But ***get***-causatives are different.  They use ***to***-infinitives:

> You *got* me **to check** a dictionary.

So there is indeed a problem with example 3; it is missing the infinitive marker ***to***.

---

Semantically speaking, ***had***-, ***let***-, and ***got***-causatives aren't really appropriate in your original context:

- ***Let*** is a **permissive causative**, but jonlink was not giving you permission to do something.
- ***Had*** is a **directive causative**, but jonlink was not directing you to do something.
- ***Got*** is an **indirect causative**, but jonlink was not persuading, inducing, or manipulating you into doing something.
- ***Make*** is a **coercive causative**, and jonlink's answer created a state of affairs that forced you to do something (check a dictionary).

The ***make***-causative is the most appropriate choice in this case.  You had to check a dictionary in order to respond to what he wrote, so the ***make***-causative is the one that fits most closely―although the type of coercion involved is rather weak.

Although this is called a coercive causative, when the coercion is particularly strong, there is a tendency to use ***force*** instead ("He *forced* me to hand over my valuables at gunpoint"), which uses a ***to***-infinitive.

---

I don't personally think using the pronoun ***you*** sounds rude, but if you wanted to avoid it anyway, you could do so by avoiding causatives altogether:

> I wasn't sure what the plural of *aspirin* was, so I **had to** check a dictionary.

Phrasing it this way focuses on you, the speaker, and avoids mentioning the other person at all, so it avoids any possible offense.

Comment: +1 Also: *Your answer led me to check a dictionary* And in the vernacular: *{You/your answer} {got me (to)/had me} checking a dictionary* are *effective* but minimally *agentive*.

Comment: Prompted me, led me and made me. This was a great lesson. Thank you all.